# Add a shell function to the stdenv based on attribute

Tags: nix

Is there a simple way to add a bash function to the environment provided by stdenv? When developing with 'nix-shell', I can run commands like 'unpackPhase' or 'buildPhase' because `mkDerivation` puts them in scope--its super useful. My derivation attributes are added to the environment as well. But I'd also like to see a way to automatically add an attribute as a function in the build/shell environment.

To explain what I'm getting at, I can currently get functions into the environment by either using `eval` statements or `toFile` and `source`. For instance, with `eval`, something like:

```
{ stdenv, ... } : stdenv.mkDerivation
{ shellHook = ''eval "$myFunctions"'';
  myFunctions = ''
    myFunction1(){
      echo "doing myFunction1"
      }
    myFunction2(){
      echo "doing myFunction2"
      }
    ''
}
```

will "source" `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` when I enter the `nix-shell`.

However, I was expecting something like a `mkFunction` utility to compliment `mkWrapper`, `mkProgram`, and other such basic utilities. I'd expect to use it like in the below, where the the attributes defined using `mkFunction` are automatically "sourced" as above.

```
{ stdenv, mkFunction, ... } : stdenv.mkDerivation
{ myFunction1 = mkFunction '' echo "doing myFunction1" '';
  myFunction2 = mkFunction '' echo "doing myFunction2" '';
  shellHook = '' echo "No need to source, myFunctions are already in scope." '';
}
```

I think such a utility would be useful. I thought [setup hooks](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-setup-hooks) might cover this use, but I'm not really sure how to use them. And its not so bad doing it the first way (If I hadn't figured it out during the course of writing the question I wouldn't have bothered asking). But it seems like the kind of utility that `nix` would already have available, so I'm asking anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup hooks can indeed do that, here's a simple example of one that defines a function `foo`:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
let
  fooHook = stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "foo-hook";
    # Setting phases directly is usually discouraged, but in this case we really
    # only need fixupPhase because that's what installs setup hooks
    phases = [ "fixupPhase" ];
    setupHook = writeText "my-setup-hook" ''
      foo() { echo "Foo was called!"; }
    '';
  };
in mkShell {
  buildInputs = [ fooHook ];
  shellHook = "foo";
}
```

Running `nix-shell` on this yields the desired result:

```
$ nix-shell
Foo was called!
[nix-shell:~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple possibility is to use the `runHook` function provided by stdenv.

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
mkShell rec {
  name = "runs-hook";
  myFun = "echo The name is ${name}";
}
```

In the snippet above, a variable `myFun` is made available in the shell/build environment. You call it with:

```
> runHook myFun
The name is runs-hook
```

This is really similar to the `eval` method from the question.